# An old children's series about a wizard and dreams?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dreams

I was born in 1992 and live in a country where most cartoons might have probably aired years after their original time but the one I'm talking about is certainly before 2002.
I remember it being about an old man, probably a wizard who once went into a kid's dream and helped the boy overcome his fear of video games because the boy was afraid of a goalkeeper or something. The wizard had a moon shape hat, a white beard with no mustache, and a blue robe with star shapes on it. Sorry it might not sound much but it's all I've got. It's both cartoonish and real characters.

Comment: Makes me think s bit of the Dreammaker from *The Dreamstone* https://images.app.goo.gl/Reo241mXnyELQJea9

Comment: Cross-posted to Reddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/cartoons/comments/daajbm/an_old_childrens_series_about_a_wizard_and_dreams/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: @FuzzyBoots similar but not the one I was looking for. And is cross-posting somehow inappropriate? I'm not really used to regulations in here

Comment: Nah, it just lets us know if we run into it during our searched.

Comment: Also, there's a guide at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to help you refine your question. Just edit any new details in.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots again, that page is not very good on mobile—I recommend https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999 instead because of this.

Comment: @Stormblessed: I should bookmark that one. I usually find the other one by clicking on the story-identification tag and then going to Learn More.